# VLOOKUP function does not work

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to implement a simple lookup that uses the classes below and the corresponding grade.

```
     Class             Grade
From        to  
 19         20           1
 17         18          1,5
 14         15           2
 12         13          2,5
 10         11           3
 7           9          3,5
 4           6           4
 2           3          4,5
 0           1           5
```

In my example I have the search criterion 14 which should give out the grade 2.
Assuming the matrix to be located in the cells A1:C11 and the search criterion in cell E10, the following function gives me the value of 5, but why? The 3 in the formula refers to column 3, which is the value  I want to receive.

```
=VLOOKUP(E10;A1:C11;3)
```

Thank you for your useful hints and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=index(c:c; match(e10; a:a; -1))
```

The default True for approximate lookup in VLOOKUP wants the data sorted in ascending order, not descending. MATCH uses 1 for ascending and -1 for descending.

Comment: Thanks, the hint with the ascending and descending order was very useful. It worked by rewriting the table in ascending order!

Answer (score 0):

Your Vlookup is missing the last parameter

=VLOOKUP(E10;A1:C11;3)  returns an approximate result.

=VLOOKUP(E10;A1:C11;3;0) returns the exact result of your search.

Comment: I believe the approximate match was intentional.

Comment: Thanks for your hint